# Send crash reports only over Wifi

Tags: android, crashlytics

We have app with very limited network connection. So we don't want to spend it for nothing. There is also been released new API for Android `JobScheduler`. It would make sense to decide when to send crash reports for ex. only when connected to Wifi. Do crashlytics have smth similar or am I missing smth?

Comment: do you found any way to restrict crashlyics to report crashes only on wifi?

Comment: @TalKanel no, if you have doubts about crashlytics, better to use internal solutions like ACRA etc.

Comment: ok. thanks for the suggestion